Does it still count time when pressing home?
I used to think pausing and then pressing home it would stop counting the time that it says I've played but then I just saved then went somewhere after pausing and pressing home and then saved again to close the game and it went up by like 15 mins! So does it pause the time or not and does just normally pausing also work?

Actually, in this game, the in-game timer keeps running even when you press the Home button or pause the game. The in-game timer is designed to track the total amount of time you have the game running, regardless of whether you're actively playing, in a menu, or paused.
Pausing the game (by pressing the + button to bring up the pause menu) will stop gameplay but will not stop the in-game timer. The timer keeps counting the time the game is running, even if it's paused.
If you are trying to minimize the recorded playtime, the best approach would be to save your game and turn off the console completely.
To turn off the Wii console, press and hold the power button on the front of the console until the red light appears. Alternatively, you can press and hold the power button on the Wii Remote until the console powers down.

sigh thats why it says 72 hours...
